# which one should I used for calculating F1 score in pytorch?

Tags: python, image, testing, pytorch, imbalanced-data

I am using pretriend model to classify two classes and i want to compute the F1 score and weghted F1 score and first I calculate the precision  and  Sensitivity based on the results of CM and claculate the F1 score and i get good results ,but i try to use classification_report() library but give me lowe results the code below is what i used
this is the manual calculation for F1 score

```
def test_model(model,dataloaders,checkpointdevice):
    CM=0
    model.load_state_dict(last_model_cp['model_state_dict'])
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in test2_dataloader:
            images, labels = data
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            
            outputs = model(images) #file_name
            preds = torch.argmax(outputs.data, 1)
            CM+=confusion_matrix(labels.cpu(), preds.cpu(),labels=[0,1])
            
        tn=CM[0][0]
        tp=CM[1][1]
        fp=CM[0][1]
        fn=CM[1][0]
        acc=np.sum(np.diag(CM)/np.sum(CM))
        sensitivity=tp/(tp+fn)
        precision=tp/(tp+fp)
        
        print('\nTestset Accuracy(mean): %f %%' % (100 * acc))
        print()
        print('Confusion Matirx : ')
        print(CM)
        print('- Sensitivity : ',(tp/(tp+fn))*100)
        print('- Specificity : ',(tn/(tn+fp))*100)
        print('- Precision: ',(tp/(tp+fp))*100)
        print('- NPV: ',(tn/(tn+fn))*100)
        print('- F1 : ',((2*sensitivity*precision)/(sensitivity+precision))*100)
        print()
                
    return acc, CM
```

the output:

```
Testset Accuracy(mean): 79.914301 %

Confusion Matirx : 
[[ 389  259]
 [ 116 1103]]
- Sensitivity :  90.48400328137818
- Specificity :  60.03086419753087
- Precision:  80.98384728340675
- NPV:  77.02970297029704
- F1 :  85.47074777218133

(0.799143010176754, array([[ 389,  259],
        [ 116, 1103]]))
```

and this is how i used the classification report library ```

```
CM=0
# x = torch.empty(0, 30)
model.load_state_dict(last_model_cp['model_state_dict'])
model.eval()
all_labels = []
all_preds = []
with torch.no_grad():
  for data in test2_dataloader:
            images, labels = data
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            outputs = model(images) #file_name
            preds = torch.argmax(outputs.data, 1)
            all_labels.append(labels.cpu())
            all_preds.append(preds.cpu())
            CM+=confusion_matrix(labels.cpu(), preds.cpu(),labels=[0,1])
            # x.append(f1(all_preds, labels))
all_labels = torch.cat(all_labels).numpy()
all_preds = torch.cat(all_preds).numpy()
# all_preds_binary = all_preds > 0 
# F12=mean(F1)
```

and this is the output :

```
            precision    recall  f1-score   support

      class0       0.77      0.60      0.67       648
      class1       0.81      0.90      0.85      1219

    accuracy                           0.80      1867
   macro avg       0.79      0.75      0.76      1867
weighted avg       0.80      0.80      0.79      1867

array([[ 389,  259],
       [ 116, 1103]])
```

I have been tried every method mentioned in online to get the same results of manual F1 score calculation, I think my code has something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryConfusionMatrix
from torchmetrics.classification import BinaryStatScores

confmat = BinaryConfusionMatrix()
stats = BinaryStatScores()

#your loop:
#   here you should append prediction and groundtruth label 

#after the loop you can calculate the confusion matrix 
y_pred = torch.tensor(y_pred)
y_true = torch.tensor(y_true)

print(f'\nConfusionMatrix: \n{confmat(y_pred, y_true).cpu().numpy()}')
stats_scores = stats(y_pred, y_true)
print(f'\ntp: {stats_scores[0]}, fp: {stats_scores[1]},'
              f' tn: {stats_scores[2]}, fn: {stats_scores[3]},'
              f' sup: {stats_scores[4]}')
```